# Google Fusion Table Query Lat/Long Returns More than 1 Row

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to get a census tract from a fusion table with KML shape data in 1 column - called geometry. Generally everything is working great, but there is at least 1 case where the query is returning 2 rows because 1 shape basically surrounds the other. How do I determine which shape the point is actually in?

My query is:
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT CensusTract, Percentile, Score FROM MYTABLE WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + lat + ', ' + lng + '),10))

Which returns 2 rows if you have a Lat/Long of 37.121988/-120.26532400000002
"kind":"fusiontables#sqlresponse","columns":["CensusTract","Percentile","Score"],"rows":[["6039000202","86-90",45.78937664],["6039000300","66-70",31.5619351]]}

I tried using ST_DISTANCE in the order by but my syntax was fouled up. Plus, I'm not sure what I would use as the field. I tried this:
ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(geometry, LATLNG(' + lat + ', ' + lng + '))

Happy to provide more info if needed and appreciate any assistance.

Chris

Comment: This is my full request which is giving a Bad Request error. https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT CensusTract, Percentile, Score FROM MYTABLE WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,CIRCLE(LATLNG(37.121988, -120.26532400000002),10)) ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(geometry, LATLNG(37.121988, -120.26532400000002))&key=MYKEY

Comment: What is your table?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the issue. You can't have a where condition with a spatial component and an order by with a spatial component. the spatial limit is 1. For anyone interested, this is how I figure it out https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/fusiontables/v2/fusiontables.query.sql

Comment: You should put your answer as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I figured out the issue. You can't have a where condition with a spatial component and an order by with a spatial component. The spatial limit is 1. For anyone interested, this is how I figured it out https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/fusiontables/v2/fusiontables.query.sql